# Adjust the vertical space at the bottom of the page

Tags: latex

I need to adjust to vertical space between the last line that fits in the page and the bottom of the page itselft beacuse at the moment it looks like 1/4 of the page is empty because the "writable" part of the page ends too soon. Above image for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i have found out how to do it, just type the following:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  bottom=10mm
}
```

Other info on the geometry package here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins